# How to call a Win 8 project from a Winforms project?

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-8.1

I have an existing Winforms project that currently runs on our Win 7 machines. Now I need to add camera access to it so that we can also run it on Win 8.1 tablets and take photos.

I understand that I can build WPF application for Win 8.1 to access camera.
I know that I can run my Winforms application on Win 8.1 as is.

My question is - do I *have to* rewrite my whole winforms application into Win 8.1 WPF to get access to the camera, or I can somehow create just the image capture form in Win 8.1 WPF and call it from my existing Winform application?

I was hoping that creating WPF Custom Control would work, but it seems that I only can create WPF Custom Controls for Windows 7, not for Win 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - do I have to rewrite my whole winforms application
>   into Win 8.1 WPF to get access to the camera...

You can use `Version` to check if an OS is Win8, then do appropriate actions.

```
Version win8Version = new Version(6, 2, 9200, 0);

if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
    Environment.OSVersion.Version >= win8Version)
{
    // Win8 or higher
}
else
{
     // Do something if it isn't
}
```

Comment: The real problem is that I do not seem to be able to reference a Win 8 project form Win32 project.

Comment: That problem you can use Reflection. When a check tell that current ver is Windows 8, you can use this technicque to work with other assembly. If you can persuade user install `.Net Framework 4.0` on win7 os, it is much easier to do this.